# Resource controller functions are not triggered when using the main route in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am building a web app, and I want to use the resource controller but when I try to go to `/$id`,it should run the show method but it simply returns a 404 error.
I have defined the route as the main root as,

```
Route::resource('/','StoresController');
```

Now, when i use the following route, it works just fine and all the methods work just fine too.

```
Route::resource('store','StoresController');
```

Comment: It seems like a resource controller has to be named. You could try to Redirect your (/) route to the 'store'.

Comment: apparantly it works but still the url is /store. any solution for this? thanks